# Django groups and permissions

Tags: python, django, permissions, decorator

I would like to create 2 groups (Professors, Students). And I would like to restrict students from creating and deleting Courses.

views.py:

```
def is_professor(function=None):

    def _is_professor(u):
      if user.groups.filter(name='Professor').exists():
          return True
      else:
          raise HttpResponseForbidden
  return _is_professor(function)

class ListCourseView(ListView):

    model = Course
    template_name = 'course_list.html'
    fields = '__all__'

@is_professor
class CreateCourseView(CreateView):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
             return False

    model = Course
    template_name = 'course/edit_course.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('courses-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

         context = super(CreateCourseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('courses-new')

        return context

class UpdateCourseView(UpdateView):

    model = Course
    template_name = 'course/edit_course.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('courses-list')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(UpdateCourseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['action'] = reverse('courses-edit',
                                kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})

    return context

class DeleteCourseView(DeleteView):

    model = Course
    template_name = 'course/delete_course.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('courses-list')
```

models.py

```
 class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([
        self.name
        ])



class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        permissions = ( ('add_course', 'Add course'), )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is what I tried. First of all I get an error

> NameError: global name 'user' is not defined.

And secondly I still don't think this would work :)

Answer (score 13):

Something that i did for one of my django project is :

I defined a function that will check permissions and if user is authenticated :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def group_required(*group_names):
    """Requires user membership in at least one of the groups passed in."""
    def in_groups(u):
        if u.is_authenticated():
            if bool(u.groups.filter(name__in=group_names)) | u.is_superuser:
                return True
        return False

    return user_passes_test(in_groups, login_url='403')
```

And then i passed this function as decorator for my functions :

```
from whatever import group_required

@group_required('Professor')
def action_only_for_professor(request):
    # do things

@group_required('Student')
def action_only_for_student(request):
    # do other things
```

With this method you can declare multi-group for your functions like this :

```
@group_required('Professor', 'Student', 'Administrator', ...)
```

This trick work only with method that you create.
if you want to do the same for class, i suggest you to check django-braces (e.q. http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).
Django Braces works like this :

```
from braces.views import GroupRequiredMixin

class CreateCourseView(CreateView, GroupRequiredMixin):
    group_required = u"Professor"

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
             return False

    model = Course
    template_name = 'course/edit_course.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('courses-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

         context = super(CreateCourseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('courses-new')

        return context
```

If you want to use more than one group permission in your class, just do it like this :

```
group_required = [u"Professor", u"Student", u"Administrator", etc...]
```

Django-braces is very powerful to check permissions for your class, in the sense that you can check if a user is authenticated (with LoginRequiredMixin), is anonymous (AnonymousrequiredMixin), is superuser (SuperuserRequiredMixin), got one (PermissionRequiredMixin) or multiple permissions (MultiplePermissionRequiredMixin), and more and more stuff ! You just have to inherit your class with the appropriate mixin you want to use ;)

Hope it will help, and waiting for your return about all that :)

Comment: Oh and i forgot, to use the group_required decorator, or django braces mixin, you have to create your differents groups in your django project, obviously :)

Comment: I'm still able to create course with all users using 2nd way (braces)...
Why is there 'u' infront of group_name?

Comment: I'm not sure, there is no such informations about that on django-braces, but for python, it should considers the string as unicode, the interest of the u infront of group_name.

Comment: Is this OK way to create groups?


professor = Group(name='Professors')
ContentType.objects.get(app_label='course', model='course')

can_view = Permission(name='Can View', codename='can_view_something',
                       content_type=somemodel_ct)


can_modify = Permission(name='Can Modify', codename='can_modify_something',
                       content_type=somemodel_ct)

can_create = Permission(name='Can Create', codename='can_create_something',
                       content_type=somemodel_ct)

When i go to /admin page i see Professors group, but there are no selected permissions

Comment: In your admin, you can manage your users permissions, you can if you want add one/more permissions specifically to users, or you can add permissions to a group and assign an user to this group. I prefer the second way (but that's personal). You can too decided to create groups from your /admin, or you can create them programatically, i refer you to this page to see how : [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization]

Comment: in /admin page, there is none chosen permission for any user but they still can do everything(except logging to admin page ofc). Nevertheless i would like to add permissions and groups programatically but aparently i dont know how :/ .

Comment: Do your users have a permission group or some permissions ?
You can add groups into the "Group" item in your admin sidebar.
You can add a group to a user, into the detail of this user, in your admin.

Answer (score 0):

i think the first error is because user is not defined here

```
def is_professor(function=None):

    def _is_professor(u):
      if user.groups.filter(name='Professor').exists():
          return True
      else:
          raise HttpResponseForbidden
  return _is_professor(function)
```

in the function _is_professor(u) it should be request.user

Comment: when i change 'u' to 'user' i get a new error:
AttributeError: type object 'CreateCourseView' has no attribute 'groups'
I tried adding groups on /admin page but it doesnt seem to be working..

Comment: if i write it like this :
def _is_professor(request):
  user = request.user
  if user.groups.filter(name='Professor').exists():
   return True
  else:
   raise HttpResponseForbidden
 return _is_professor(function)


    AttributeError: type object 'CreateCourseView' has no attribute 'user' . 
I think problem is in models.py i need to create groups or smthing..