# adding a user to a group on djngo admin and accessing it via views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

if I add a user to a group on Django admin and assign permissions to the group, can I reference that user and its permissions in the views of my project?
if yes how do I do it?
thanks

Comment: Is this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36179566/13773284

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django groups and permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177769/django-groups-and-permissions)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).